# Constructing sparse matrix from list of lists of tuples

Tags: python, constructor, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a Python list of row information for a sparse matrix. Each row is represented as a list of (column, value) tuples.  Call it `alist`:

```
alist = [[(1,10), (3,-3)],
         [(2,12)]]
```

How can I efficiently construct a scipy sparse matrix from this list of lists, resulting in a matrix like this:

```
0  10   0  -3
0   0  12   0
```

The obvious approach is to make a `scipy.sparse.lil_matrix`, which internally has this "list of lists" structure.  But from the [scipy.sparse.lil_matrix — SciPy v0.19.0 Reference Guide](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.lil_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.lil_matrix) I see just three ways of constructing them:

- starting from a dense array
- starting from another sparse array
- just constructing an empty array

So the only way to get fresh data in is either to solve this problem with some other sparse matrix representation, or to start with a dense array, neither of which address the initial problem, and both of which seem likely to be less efficient representations than `lil_matrix` itself for this data.

I guess I can make an empty one, and use a loop to add values, but surely I'm missing something.

The scipy documentation is really frustrating when it comes to sparse matrices.

Comment: See also, https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21909

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your data layout is an unusual one.  Here's my first stab at using it.

```
In [565]: M = sparse.lil_matrix((2,4), dtype=int)
In [566]: M
Out[566]: 
<2x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 0 stored elements in LInked List format>
In [567]: for i,row in enumerate(alist):
     ...:     for col in row:
     ...:         M[i, col[0]] = col[1]
     ...:         
In [568]: M
Out[568]: 
<2x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 3 stored elements in LInked List format>
In [569]: M.A
Out[569]: 
array([[ 0, 10,  0, -3],
       [ 0,  0, 12,  0]])
```

Yes, it is iterative; and `lil` is the best format for that purpose.

Or using the common `coo` style of inputs:

```
In [580]: data,col,row = [],[],[]
In [581]: for i, rr in enumerate(alist):
     ...:     for cc in rr:
     ...:         row.append(i)
     ...:         col.append(cc[0])
     ...:         data.append(cc[1])
     ...:         
In [582]: data,col,row
Out[582]: ([10, -3, 12], [1, 3, 2], [0, 0, 1])
In [583]: M1=sparse.coo_matrix((data,(row,col)),shape=(2,4))
In [584]: M1
Out[584]: 
<2x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 3 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [585]: M1.A
Out[585]: 
array([[ 0, 10,  0, -3],
       [ 0,  0, 12,  0]])
```

Another option is to create the blank `lil` matrix, and directly fill in its attributes:

In other words, start with:

```
In [591]: m.data
Out[591]: array([[], []], dtype=object)
In [592]: m.rows
Out[592]: array([[], []], dtype=object)
```

and change them to:

```
In [587]: M.data
Out[587]: array([[10, -3], [12]], dtype=object)
In [588]: M.rows
Out[588]: array([[1, 3], [2]], dtype=object)
```

It would still require the 2 level iteration on your `alist` structure.

```
In [593]: for i, rr in enumerate(alist):
     ...:     for cc in rr:
     ...:         m.rows[i].append(cc[0])
     ...:         m.data[i].append(cc[1])       
In [594]: m
Out[594]: 
<2x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 3 stored elements in LInked List format>
In [595]: m.A
Out[595]: 
array([[ 0, 10,  0, -3],
       [ 0,  0, 12,  0]])
```

---

In another comment you mentioned the difficulty in understanding the `csr` `indptr`.  The easiest way to get that is to convert one these formats:

```
In [597]: Mr=M.tocsr()
In [598]: Mr.indptr
Out[598]: array([0, 2, 3], dtype=int32)
In [599]: Mr.data
Out[599]: array([10, -3, 12])
In [600]: Mr.indices
Out[600]: array([1, 3, 2], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Such a clear, helpful, detailed answer - thank you! The constructor based on the COO format seems most natural, and I could come up with some generators to produce it and achieve a memory- and time-efficient input pipeline. I hope the scipy folks add some examples like this in a way that people would find them. This is the format my data came in, and given the number of systems that support all these different sparse formats, as discussed at [Sparse array - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_array), I'd think more people would exchange data using them.

Comment: I first worked with sparse matrices in MATLAB for finite element problems.  There the `coo` style of input is the only option, though internally it stores the data as `csc` (at least that's format it saves to `.mat` files).  Most of sparse math was developed for linear algebra problems.  `scipy` adds a number of formats (note the links in the Wiki article).  Now much of the sparse matrix interest is coming from big-data problems, sparse feature matrices, machine learning, linguistics, and such.  `scikit learn` for example adds some of its own compiled sparse matrix utilities.

Comment: I find it surprising the original data structure of the OP would be considered unusual (contrary to a comment above)

Answer (score 9):

If you have the whole `alist` before creating the sparse matrix, there is no need to use `lil_matrix`, since that is optimized for incrementally updating the sparse matrix.

If you want to do any sort of arithmetic with the matrix afterwords, `csr_matrix` is  probably your best choice. You can construct the `csr_matrix` directly by using `(data, (row, column))` format, like this:

```
In [40]: alist = [[(1,10), (3,-3)],
    ...:          [(2,12)]]

In [41]: i, j, data = zip(*((i, t[0], t[1]) for i, row in enumerate(alist) for t in row))

In [42]: (i, j, data)
Out[42]: ((0, 0, 1), (1, 3, 2), (10, -3, 12))

In [43]: csr_matrix((data, (i, j)), shape=(2, 4)).todense()
Out[43]: 
matrix([[ 0, 10,  0, -3],
        [ 0,  0, 12,  0]], dtype=int64)
```

If efficiency is a real concern, you can create the `csr_matrix` internal format (using indptr) directly:

```
In [57]: indptr = np.cumsum([0] + [len(row) for row in alist])

In [58]: j, data = zip(*(t for row in alist for t in row))

In [59]: csr_matrix((data, j, indptr), shape=(2, 4)).todense()
Out[59]: 
matrix([[ 0, 10,  0, -3],
        [ 0,  0, 12,  0]])
```

If you're converting to pandas afterwords, `coo_matrix` is the way to go, since pandas converts to `coo_matrix` anyway:

```
In [41]: i, j, data = zip(*((i, t[0], t[1]) for i, row in enumerate(alist) for t in row))

In [43]: coo_matrix((data, (i, j)), shape=(2, 4))
```

Comment: Thanks for the deliberation! and actually, in my particular case, I just need it as a sparse feature matrix alongside other dataframe columns, that can be lightly munged and looked at with pandas, before fitting an sklearn model (`.fit`) over it.

Comment: In that case coo_matrix is the way to go, since pandas anyway converts to that format

Comment: Is providing the shape to `coo_matrix` performance-wise helpful/necessary? it works even without that!

Comment: If you don't provide the shape, coo_matrix will deduce it from shape = (max(i), max(j)). This can lead to problems if for instance the last column or last row is all zeros, as you will lose that row/column from the matrix.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a `dict` of positions and values from the list of (column, value) tuples `alist` and then use `dok_matrix` to construct the sparse matrix

```
>>> d = {(i,j):v for i,l in enumerate(alist) for j,v in l}
>>> d
{(0, 1): 10, (0, 3): -3, (1, 2): 12}
>>> 
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> m = max(d.keys(), key=itemgetter(0))[0] + 1
>>> n = max(d.keys(), key=itemgetter(1))[1] + 1
>>> m,n
(2, 4)
>>>
>>> from scipy.sparse import dok_matrix
>>> S = dok_matrix((m,n), dtype=int)
>>> for pos,v in d.items():
...     S[pos] = v
... 
>>> S.todense()
matrix([[ 0, 10,  0, -3],
        [ 0,  0, 12,  0]])
>>>
```

Comment: When end with `.todense()` though?

Comment: Any reason absolutely requiring `itemgetter` here?

Comment: @matanster. `.todense()` is just to show how the matrix looks like

Comment: @matanster. `itemgetter` is not necessary. We just need to get the dimensions automatically. You can replace it with `lambda t: t[0]`. So it would look like `m = max(d.keys(), key=lambda t: t[0])[0] + 1` and  `n = max(d.keys(), key=lambda t: t[1])[1] + 1`

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to post another answer using `coo_matrix`, It is a fast format for constructing sparse matrices.

```
>>> alist = [[(1, 10), (3, -3)], [(2, 12)]]
>>> row, col, data = zip(*((i,j,v) for i,l in enumerate(alist) for j,v in l))
>>>
>>> from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
>>> S = coo_matrix((data, (row, col)), (max(row)+1,max(col)+1), dtype=np.int8)
>>> S.todense()
matrix([[ 0, 10,  0, -3],
        [ 0,  0, 12,  0]], dtype=int8)
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Posted solutions can be summarized in three steps: **add row numbers, explode row data, extract coordinates and data**. Here is a bit more elaborative implementation with iterators:

```py
alist = [[(1,10), (3,-3)],[(2,12)]]

import itertools
from scipy import sparse

# add row ids

it = enumerate(alist)
# explode row data by id
it = map(lambda t: itertools.product([t[0]],*t[1:]), it)
it = itertools.chain(*it)
# flatten tupples
it = map(lambda t: (t[0],*t[1]), it)
# extract coordinates and data 
i,j,data=zip(*it)
# use coo format
sparse.coo_matrix((data,(i,j)))
```