# Get Highest Topic Probability in each document in Gensim LDA

Tags: python, gensim, lda, topic-modeling

so my case is, i want to know the topic probability in each document. i'm using get_document_topics() in gensim. here's my code

```
tops = ldamodel.get_document_topics(bow_corpus, minimum_probability=0.3, minimum_phi_value=None, per_word_topics=False)
for topic in tops:
  print(topic)
```

and the result:
[get_document_topics result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaYMI.png)

```
[(2, 0.99672836)]
[(2, 0.996824)]
[(2, 0.99556035)]
[(2, 0.9955946)]
[(2, 0.9959556)]
[(2, 0.99638283)]
[(2, 0.9967755)]
[(2, 0.9944522)]
[(0, 0.99699086)]
[(0, 0.9832064)]
[(2, 0.987699)]
[(2, 0.9829938)]
[(0, 0.7324285)]
[(0, 0.32443014), (2, 0.67167395)]
[(2, 0.9904447)]
[(0, 0.877132)]
[(2, 0.9840625)]
[(2, 0.9931089)]
[(2, 0.99166435)]
[(0, 0.94476527)]
[(0, 0.6203844), (2, 0.3713088)]
[(2, 0.99007285)]
[(2, 0.9924469)]
[(2, 0.9086308)]
[(1, 0.37694806), (2, 0.6170092)]
[(2, 0.9940049)]
[(0, 0.9859114)]
[(0, 0.65609944), (2, 0.3391403)]
[(2, 0.98799)]
[(0, 0.99270225)]
[(0, 0.7916958)]
[(1, 0.7091656)]
[(1, 0.5757512), (2, 0.4185949)]
```

my question: is it possible to get only topic probability with the highest score in each document? so i expecting the output 1 document only has 1 topic probability (the highest probability). thank you

Answer (score 0):

The output of `get_document_topics` encodes a sparse matrix of shape `n_docs x n_topics`.

The difficulty comes from **gensim's sparse matrix representation** as a list of lists of tuples. Encode into a **more standard scipy formats to handle the question easily**. The `gensim.matutils` module provides a [general converter](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/matutils.html#gensim.matutils.corpus2csc) between the formats (the converter is applicable beyond what its name suggests).

With the data in question

```py
import gensim
docs_topics = [
    [(2, 0.99672836)],
    [(2, 0.996824)],
    [(2, 0.99556035)],
    [(2, 0.9955946)],
    [(2, 0.9959556)],
    [(2, 0.99638283)],
    [(2, 0.9967755)],
    [(2, 0.9944522)],
    [(0, 0.99699086)],
    [(0, 0.9832064)],
    [(2, 0.987699)],
    [(2, 0.9829938)],
    [(0, 0.7324285)],
    [(0, 0.32443014), (2, 0.67167395)],
    [(2, 0.9904447)],
    [(0, 0.877132)],
    [(2, 0.9840625)],
    [(2, 0.9931089)],
    [(2, 0.99166435)],
    [(0, 0.94476527)],
    [(0, 0.6203844), (2, 0.3713088)],
    [(2, 0.99007285)],
    [(2, 0.9924469)],
    [(2, 0.9086308)],
    [(1, 0.37694806), (2, 0.6170092)],
    [(2, 0.9940049)],
    [(0, 0.9859114)],
    [(0, 0.65609944), (2, 0.3391403)],
    [(2, 0.98799)],
    [(0, 0.99270225)],
    [(0, 0.7916958)],
    [(1, 0.7091656)],
    [(1, 0.5757512), (2, 0.4185949)]
]
```

this one-liner does the job

```py
gensim.matutils.corpus2csc(docs_topics).argmax(axis=0)
```

giving the output

```
matrix([[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0,
 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1]])
```

For instance, for the last document we choose topic 1 as more likely  than 2 (0.58 versus 0.42).

See also [hand-made converters suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43618956/constructing-sparse-matrix-from-list-of-lists-of-tuples/76400623#76400623).